# Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, poi-hssf

I am getting a null pointer exception, but I dont know why. I checked to see if the cell was null before I read it to a string. So, why is that string null?

```
private void fillArray() 
{
    try 
    {
        readBook = new HSSFWorkbook(readFile);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("If we know what we're doing, no one should ever see this line.");
    }
    if (readBook != null) 
    {HSSFSheet infoSheet = readBook.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFRow headingsRow = infoSheet.getRow(0);
        int i = 0;
        HSSFCell cell = headingsRow.getCell(i);
        String columnHeading = cell.toString();
        while (cell != null && !(cell.toString().equals(""))) 
        {
            cell = headingsRow.getCell(i);
            columnHeading = cell.toString();
            columnHeadings.add(columnHeading);
            i++;
        }
        if(columnListIsSetup == false)
        {
            createList();
            columnListIsSetup = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are lots of places that *could* be throwing NullPointerException - what does the stack trace say?

Comment: It traces the exception to the line                             columnHeading = cell.toString();

Comment: Then that shows that `cell` is null... or that it's being thrown within `toString`.

Comment: Yes, but the cell is NOT null, it will even println its contents, just not store it.

Comment: Then it must be the implementation of `toString` that's throwing the exception. (Except I suspect that actually `cell` *is* null, and you're just misdiagnosing it.)

Comment: OK, I changes .toString() to .getStringCellValue() and it still throws exception. Also, the cell deininetley is not null or else it would never execute the while loop.

Comment: Um, you're checking *before you assign a new value to `cell`*. There's nothing to say that `cell` won't be null after the first line of the body of the `while` loop. (Added an answer to that effect.)

Comment: cell is null. The first line in the while loop reassigns what null is, therefore, making the null check in the while loop condition fairly useless in this particular case.

Comment: ^ i added an answer which could help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the problem:

```
while (cell != null && !(cell.toString().equals(""))) 
{
    // We know that cell isn't null before this line...
    cell = headingsRow.getCell(i);

    // ... but now we've got a new value for cell, which could be null
    columnHeading = cell.toString();
    columnHeadings.add(columnHeading);
    i++;
}
```

I suspect you want to change it to:

```
while (cell != null && !(cell.toString().equals(""))) 
{
    // We know cell isn't null for this...
    columnHeading = cell.toString();
    columnHeadings.add(columnHeading);

    i++;
    // It's fine to set cell to null here... we'll be
    // checking again in a second...
    cell = headingsRow.getCell(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (cell != null && !(cell.toString().equals("")))  {
    cell = headingsRow.getCell(i);      // here, cell gets reassigned so the 
                                        // "cell != null" check in the while 
                                        // loop condition loses it's value,
                                        // you need to check again

    if (cell == null)       // add the following to make sure the NEW cell value is not null
        break;              //

    columnHeading = cell.toString();
    columnHeadings.add(columnHeading);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before making sure cell is null (or) empty, you are doing `String columnHeading = cell.toString();` which could be causing the NullPointerException in case where cell is null.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, and still getting the exception. Its so weird because I was doing it randomly, and now every time I run it I get that exception, and nothing was  changed.